# Impossible to run a Florencenet node 9.0~rc1 when another node is running despite different port

Tags: node

I have a node running on Edo2net using tezos-client v8.2 with RPC port 8732.

When I try to run another node on different port (8733) and different data dir, it's ok.

But when I try to run a tezos-node 9.0~rc1, for Florencenet, on port 8733 and different data dir, it fails :

> Another tezos node is probably running on one of these addresses
> (127.0.0.1:8733). Please choose another RPC port.

When I stop my Edo2net node (port 8732), I can start my Florencenet on 8733.

It seems v9.0~rc1 only cares about default port.

Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself :

Contrary to what error message says about RPC port, the problem comes from node listening port.

I updated my config.json to set 9733 instead of default 9732, and it's now ok.